# How to prevent "Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:" When writing items to AWS DynamoDB

Tags: amazon-web-services, amazon-ec2, amazon-dynamodb, aws-cli

I created a JSON file that has a few items I want to upload to an AWS DynamoDB table. I named the file request-items.json. However, when I run the command:
`aws dynamodb batch-write-item --request-items file://request-items.json`  in the AWS CLI, I get the error:

```
Error parsing parameter '--request-items': Expected: '=', received: 'EOF' for input:

^
```

I am in the current directory where the request-items.json file is located when I run the command. While doing some side research I saw that the most common cause for this error is not following the file:// protocol rules that AWS enforces. Since this is in my command, I am not sure where I am going wrong.

An Example of the JSON file I am trying to upload is:

```
{
    "Sensors": [
        {   
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": { 
                    "Sensor": { "S": "Banana" }
                }
            }
        },
        {   
            "PutRequest": {
                "Item": { 
                    "Sensor": { "S": "Orange" }
                }
            }
        }
    ]
}
```

Comment: Running on Linux? Is the content of request-items.json compatible with that described [here](https://docs.aws.amazon.com/cli/latest/reference/dynamodb/batch-write-item.html)? Could you add a non-sensitive version of your JSON file to your question.

Comment: Related: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/60087984/aws-cli-error-parsing-parameter-item-expected-received-for-inpu

Comment: @jarmod I have added the JSON file to the question

Comment: I'm not sure it matters (even though Windows is a pain) but is this Windows, Mac, Linux, other?

Comment: Seems to parse OK on Mac and Windows. I'd double check the contents of your JSON file.

Comment: @jarmod I will have to double check the syntax later. But I am running on the AWS CLI which is Linux.